# Slingshot Always Returns to Anchor Point When touchesMoved Stops

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I have a pretty basic slingshot that has two physics bodies attached to one another using a SKPhysicsSpringJoint. When touches begin, I create a projectile and spring. When touches are moved, I move the projectile accordingly to the user's touch position. When touches end, the projectile is launched.

The issue is whenever the user stops moving the projectile, but doesn't let go, the projectile moves towards its anchor point and swings around it until the user releases their touch. I've been working for hours trying to figure out why this is happening, any ideas?

Here are the main functions:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

        //Add Cannon Ball
        var uniqueID:Int = nodeArray.count
        var uniqueString = "cannonBall\(uniqueID)"




        var cannonBall = CannonBallNode(location: CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: 200))
        cannonBall.name = uniqueString

        // 3 - Determine offset of location to projectile
        let offset = touchLocation - cannonBall.position

        // 4 - Bail out if you click above cannon
        if (offset.y > 50) { return }

        self.addChild(cannonBall)
        println("\(nodeArray.count)")


        if var cannon = childNodeWithName("cannon") {
            if var heldCannonBall = childNodeWithName(uniqueString) {
                heldCannonBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
                var spring = SKPhysicsJointSpring.jointWithBodyA(cannon.physicsBody, bodyB: cannonBall.physicsBody, anchorA: cannon.position, anchorB: cannonBall.position)

                spring.damping = 0.4;
                spring.frequency = 1.0;

                // Add Physics
                physicsWorld.addJoint(spring)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

        var uniqueID:Int = nodeArray.count
        var uniqueString = "cannonBall\(uniqueID)"

        if var heldCannonBall = childNodeWithName(uniqueString) {
            // 3 - Determine offset of location to projectile
            let offset = touchLocation - heldCannonBall.position

            // 4 - Bail out if you are shooting down or backwards
            if (offset.y > 0) { return }

            heldCannonBall.position = touchLocation
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

        var uniqueID:Int = nodeArray.count
        var uniqueString = "cannonBall\(uniqueID)"

        if var releasedCannonBall = childNodeWithName(uniqueString) {
            var angle = CGFloat(M_PI_4)
            var magnitude:CGFloat = 1;

            releasedCannonBall.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(magnitude*cos(angle), magnitude*sin(angle)))
            releasedCannonBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        }




        runAction(SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.runBlock{[self.physicsWorld.removeAllJoints()]},
                SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1)]
        ))

        nodeArray.append("\(uniqueString)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally came across the solution! I needed to produce an update function to update the projectile's position as it was moved via the touchesMoved function. I created a global variable and had it store the location of the touch when it began and when it was moved. I threw it in the update function and voila, no more issues.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    //#1
    var uniqueID:Int = nodeArray.count
    var uniqueString = "cannonBall\(uniqueID)"
    println("\(cannonBallLocation)")
    if var releasedCannonBall = childNodeWithName(uniqueString) {
       releasedCannonBall.position = cannonBallLocation
    }
} //end func
```